# Man erwartet eine Spur von Dativ in „zu dessen“. Wo ist sie? Warum erscheint nur da der Genitiv? Oder existiert „zu dessem“?

Tags: genitive, dative, relative-clause

Betrachte man die Rolle des Bezugwortes *dessen* im folgenden Satz:

> Klaus, zu dessen Vater diese Krawatte gar nicht passt, hat […]

Wie kommt man auf solchen Satz? Anscheinend wählt man zwischen Genitiv *dessen Vater* und dem durch die Präposition *zu* veranlassten Dativ, weil gibt keine Mischung wie etwa *zu dessem* gibt.

- Ich würde gerne verstehen, wie diese zwei Ebenen funktionieren. Warum wird hier Genitiv anstelle Dativ bevorzugt? D. h., warum gibt es keine Spur mehr von Dativ im Satz? Anders gesagt, warum wäre

> Klaus, zu dem Vater diese Krawatte gar nicht passt, hat […] (falsch!)

falsch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Der Dativ ist nur scheinbar verschwunden. Das sieht man, wenn man ein Adjektiv hinzufügt:

> Der Fisch, zu dessen zartem Aroma der Wein einen gelungenen Kontrapunkt bildete, schmolz auf der Zunge wie frisch gefallener Schnee.
>   (mehr Beispiele [hier](https://www.google.de/search?q=zu%20dessen%20besserem%20&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&oq=zu%20dessen%20besserem%20&aqs=chrome..69i57.19278j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=%22zu%20dessen%20gutem%22))

Wichtig ist, zu verstehen, dass das "dessen" hier kein Artikel von Aroma ist. Auch ist es kein Possessivadjektiv, so wie zum Beispiel "mein". Es ist ein Relativpronomen, das dem Nomen vorangestellt wird, aber keine Flexionsendung trägt. Die Präpositionalphrase an sich ist aber "zu + Aroma" und die ist im Dativ.
Hier ein anderes Beispiel

> Meiner Mutter schnelles Auto ist blau.

"Auto" ist Subjekt hier, und daher im Nominativ. Da es keinen Artikel hat, trägt das Adjektiv die Genusendung.

Es muss jedoch angemerkt werden, dass viele Leute das "dessen" als Artikel interpretieren und Sachen sagen und schreiben wie

> … zu dessem guten … ([Beispiele](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22zu%20dessem%22&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&oq=%22zu%20dessem%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4228j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=%22zu%20dessem%20%20guten%22))

Comment: Ach wunderbar, das lernt man in einem Kurs nie. Dann "Klaus, dessen altem Vater ich eine Krawate geschenkt habe,..." ist richtig, ne?

Comment: @c.p., so weit ich weiß ja, allerdings ist gerade dieses Beispiels eins, wo viele (ich vielleicht auch) auf die schnelle "dessem alten" sagen würden.